# Unable to perform push on array in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a social media app for learning and I got stuck in NextJs ServerSide Rendering.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const fetchedProjects = []

  const data = onSnapshot(query(collection(db, 'projects')), snapshot => {
    fetchedProjects.push(snapshot.docs[0]);
  })
  data();

  return {
    props: {
      projects: JSON.stringify(fetchedProjects)
    }
  }
}
```

the `snapshot.docs[0]` returns an Object and I am trying to push it into the fetchedProjects array, but it returns me an empty array every time. I tried multiple ways of doing it but it doesn't work like using `await onSnapshot`.

Comment: I was going to say that `onSnapshot` is a listener, like `onClick`, so you can't expect anything to happen until the REAL event arrives.  Instead you want to perform an action, such as `fetch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSnapshot` attaches a realtime listener to the database, which first gets the current data and then continues listening for changes. This means that it can be invoked multiple times, which is why it doesn't return a promise and can't be use with `await` or as the result of an `async` method: those all expect only a single result.

To return a result from the `async` method, use `getDocs` instead of `onSnapshot`.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const snapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, 'projects'));
  const fetchedProjects = [snapshot.docs[0]]

  return {
    props: {
      projects: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting multiple documents from a collection once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankVanPuffelen. It works like a charm. I am new to firebase so I didn't the details of the helper functions.